# PHP ajax call not showing ie7 or 8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following call which simply does not work in ie7 or 8 - but perfectly in everything else!

```
<script>
    $('#wishlist_icon').load('/add_wishlist.php',{
       userfromcookie:"<? echo $userfromcookie; ?>",
       PRid:"<? echo $PRid; ?>",
       cat_id:"<? echo $cat_id; ?>",
       item:"<? echo $title2; ?>"
    });
</script>
```

I have tried also the following (adding random number to URL) which did not fix the problem:

```
$random_num_for_ie = rand(5, 1500);

<script>
    $('#wishlist_icon').load('/add_wishlist.php?num_ie=<? echo $random_num_for_ie; ?>',{
       userfromcookie:"<? echo $userfromcookie; ?>",
       PRid:"<? echo $PRid; ?>",
       cat_id:"<? echo $cat_id; ?>",
       item:"<? echo $title2; ?>"
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas how I can make this work as it's a vital piece of the page.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: PHP is compiled on the server so shouldn't show up once its reached the ie7/8 browser. Can you show us what it looks like once it gets to the browser? It will help tracking down the specific issue.

Comment: Please tell me that your `<script>` tags are actually `<script type="text/javascript">`? If they are not, change them, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: please could you post instead the source code sent to the browser?

Comment: My guess is there's a character being echo'd by one of your PHP vars that IE7/8 doesn't like.  Can you post the HTML/Javascript output of the PHP?

Comment: Agreed with @TomalakGeret'kal, please (and by please, I am telling you , not asking) do not sign your posts.  It is [strictly forbidden by the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).  Additionally, [pseudo-signatures such as "thanks", "hope this helps", etc. are also considered not helpful on posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).  Please refrain from doing either in the future, as it will draw flags on your posts which may result in further moderator action.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue... I find it unreal that a stray piece of html was causing the issue, loving ie!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the HTML you are retrieving is valid.

`.load` is known to work bad with IE. Try using `$.get` or `$.ajax` instead.