# Using js, how can I get name of the day from date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get day name from date.Suppose I have date like **2014-04-02**.The name of the day should be Wednesday.How can I get this day name from the given date.I am giving my js give where I am getting numeric day like **02**...

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker(
  {
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function (date) 
    { 
      var date = $("#dateNew"+i).val();alert(date);
      var res = date.split("-"); 
      alert("Value"+res[1]);
    }
});
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771114/getting-day-from-date-using-jquery-javascript" >Getting day from date using jquery/javascript</a>

Answer (score 0):

try so:

```
var today = new Date();
var dayArray = ['Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

var day = dayArray[today.getDay()];

console.log(day);
```

Comment: No, no ,no ,no. Just use the standard javascript Date class. No need for arrays or an extra library. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50293232/760777

Answer (score 0):

Someting like this will work i guess

```
var arrDaysName= new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
var curDay = new Date();
alert(arrDaysName[curDay.getDay()]);
```

Comment: No, no ,no ,no. Just use the standard javascript Date class. No need for arrays or an extra library. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50293232/760777